# Integral of the complex-valued function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C},f(x)=\int_a^be^{imx}dx=\frac{1}{im}e^{imx}|^{b}_a,m\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometric-integrals

I have difficulties to comprehend this integral. The integral of a complex valued funcion is defined as such. If $u,v:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are real functions then $\varphi:=u+iv:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is integrable iff $u,v$ are integrable and $\int_a^b\varphi(x)dx:=\int_a^bu(x)dx+i\int_a^bv(x)dx$

That means to show that the function $e^{imx}$ is integrable just as if in the real case I would have to split the function in real and immaginary part and then connecting them again in one piece. I managed to split the function into real and immaginary part but I don't know how to proceed:

Let $m=a'+ib'$. Then $e^{imx}=e^{-b'x}\cos(a'x)+ie^{-b'x}\sin(a'x)$. I don't know how to continue with the integration part.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose $\phi =u+iv=f'+ig'$ Then $$\int_a^{b} \phi =\int_a^{b} u+i\int_a^{b} v$$ $$=\int_a^{b} f'+i\int_a^{b} g'$$ $$=f(b)-f(a)+i[g(b)-g(a)]$$ $$=\phi (b)-\phi (a).$$ Hence the formula $\int _a^{b} \phi ' =\phi (b)-\phi (a)$ holds in the complex case also. Apply this to $\phi (x)=\frac {e^{imx}} {im}$.